# trying to read first 9 positions of a Char(50) datatype column

Tags: etl, datastage, ibm-infosphere

I am trying to compare two columns one with Column1=Char(9) and other with Column2=Char(50). Need to do Column1=Column2, but I need only 1st 9 positions of column2 to be read to do the equality function. Please help.!! tried trim function as well

tried trim function as well. Please help with solution

Answer (score 1):

In a Datastage Transformer substring functionality is done via

```
columnname[1,9]
```

which means from position 1 cut 9 characters.

Comment: Note: The column length for both columns are Column1=Char(9) & Column2=Char(50), so for column2 I am getting data for first 9 positions and rest all spaces till 50th position. So I need to remove those spaces and compare only the first 9 positions alone from column2 with column1. Do let me know any info required

Comment: If you do a substring like shown it will be reduced to the length of 9 - so you should adjust it to char(9) or for simplicity to varchar